# Is delaying the effect of a Wish spell considered a ''greater effect''?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wish

Let's say I cast *Wish* to duplicate the effect of *revivify* and I want it to take effect when I was supposed to act as if I haven't died (initiative order).

In the spell description:

> > A wish can produce any one of the following effects.
> >
> > (...
> >     )
> >
> > Duplicate any other spell of 5th level or lower even if it’s of a
> >     prohibited school.
>
> (...)
>
> You may try to use a wish to produce greater effects than these,but
>    doing so is dangerous. (The wish may pervert your intent into a
>    literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment.)

Can I delay when the spell effect is activated, is that allowed (by RAW)? or Would that fall in the ''greater effects category''?

Comment: The main reason why I ask this, is because I want to pair it with a contingency spell: when I'm resurrected by my wish: activate (healing spell) that would technically give me 2 contingency. Is there another method to do this instead? (some items perhaps can do this?)

Comment: Vigor/greater Vigor would make me conscious so I guess I'll always have those on on my character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *revivify* is a 5th-level spell, and the Delay Spell metamagic feat uses a spell slot three levels higher than the spell would use otherwise, making *delayed revivify* an 8th-level spell, I would say that yes, it is a “greater effect” than copying a 5th-level spell (i.e. assuming you have prohibited Conjuration and do not have *revivify* on your spell list). Even for someone who had access to Conjuration and who could consider *revivify* a sorcerer/wizard spell, that is, could cast an 8th-level version of it, incorporating a metamagic feat you don’t have and haven’t prepared is arguably also “greater.”

Note that this also assumes you mean “your initiative next round” or at least some known, small, number of rounds later. If you mean “the round after I die, whenever that happens to be,” then Delay Spell isn’t (even remotely) capable of that, and so the described effect is far greater power than an 8th-level spell, and at that point certainly beyond the capacity of *wish*’s “safe” options.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100839/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-is-delaying-the-effect-of-a-wish-spell-considered).